# How to get search value of leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

```
enter code here
  L.control.scale({ position: 'bottomleft' }).addTo(leafletMap);
var searchcontroloption={position: 'topleft'};
 L.Control.geocoder(searchcontroloption)
.on('markgeocode', function(e) {

         })
 .addTo(leafletMap);
```

I want to get search value, which user has typed in leaflet search box is there anyway to get it.
i want to get what user has enter in serach input field of leaflet .